# How to install modules for different python version of 3.x windows

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I want to install a library that only works on python 3.7 but i also have python 3.8. I can do between 2.x and 3.x but not between 3.x verisons. Any help is appriciated thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+different+python+versions

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
py 3.x -m pip install <MODULE>
```

works!

Answer (score -2):

pip install SomePackage

Eg.

pip install numpy

pip install flask

Comment: How do I install for 3.7 but not 3.8?